# Awk for a fortran output

Tags: awk, fortran

sorry for the probably too easy question, but I am a beginner in this.

I have a FORTRAN output that looks somewhat like this:

```
xxxx   3.54D+05   yyyy
xxxx   3.89D+08   yyyy
xxxx   2.45D-04   yyyy
...
...
```

I would like to print the logarithm of the second column, but awk does not recognize this form of scientific notation. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: 3.54D+05 corresponds to 354000?

Comment: Natural log or base 10? Also, do you need the remaining columns at all, or just the log of col 2?

Comment: Yes, indeed 3.54D+05 corresponds to 354000. I do not need the rest of the columns at all. The base does not matter too much for this, I need base 10 but for that I just use log(A)/log(10). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have my Mac to hand to test this, but in the interests of getting you started, I'll have a try off the top of my head...

```
awk '{x=$2; sub(/D/,"e",x); print log(x)}' file
```

Hopefully that will pick up column 2 into variable `x` and then replace the `D` by `e`, get the log and print it... then again it may say "bailing at line 1 because Mark is clueless"....

Comment: @user3746441 Can be shorten some `awk '{sub(/D/,"e");print log($2)}'`